# How do I get a value from $emit payload with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm emitting an event with various values from my *ConversationList* (child component) to *ConversationModel* (parent component).

**Conversation List**

```
getConversation(conversation_id, receiver_id, username, avatar){
  this.$emit('open-conversation', receiver_id, conversation_id, username, avatar);
}
```

**ConversationModal**

*Vue devtools output*

```
[2,1,"Jeff","http://i.pravatar.cc/52"]
```

*Template*

```
<converstations-list v-if="showConversation == false" v-on:open-conversation="getConversation($event)"></converstations-list>
```

*Method*

```
getConversation(event){
    console.log(event.payload[0] + event.payload[1] + event.payload[2] + event.payload[2])
},
```

**Error**

> Error in event handler for "open-conversation": "TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined"

I don't get it. The event is firing and has a payload object in the `devtools` that I can't access. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in the event emitting from child component to the parent one, you will receive the parameters like you emit them :

So remove `$event` from your `getConversation` handler:

```
<converstations-list v-if="showConversation == false" v-on:open-conversation="getConversation"></converstations-list>
```

and implement the `getConversation` method as follow :

```
 getConversation(receiver_id, conversation_id, username, avatar){
     // do whatever you want with that parameters
   }
```

Comment: Thanks that works great. I'm confused as to why it works like that though.